# System.Array does not contain definition for Add

Tags: c#, arrays, compiler-errors

I am creating a blackjack game and so far I have made a card class, deck class and shoe class. The card class works the deck class works, the shoe class works but I am still working on my hand class. I created a method that throws an exception if there are already MAX_CARDS cards in the hand otherwise it adds the card to the hand and increments _cardCount but  for some reason on my code `_hand.Add(card)` says that

> System.Array does not contain a definition for Add.

Any help or guidance in the right direction would be appreciated

Here's what I have for my hand class

```
class Hand
{
    const Int32 MAX_CARDS = 12;

    private Card[] _hand = new Card[MAX_CARDS];
    private Int32 _cardCount = 0;

    public Int32 CardCount
    {
        get
        {
            return _cardCount;
        }
    }

    public void AddCard(Card card)
    {
        if (_cardCount >= MAX_CARDS)
        {
            throw new Exception("Cannot of more than 12 cards in a hand");
        }
        else
        {
            _hand.Add(card);
            _cardCount++;
        }
    }

    public Card GetCard(Int32 cardIndex)
    {
        if (cardIndex >= _cardCount)
        {
            throw new Exception("Invalid Entry");
        }
        else
        {
            return _hand[cardIndex];
        }
    }

    Int32[] cardValues = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10 };
    String[] cardSymbols = { "A", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K" };

    private Int32 SymbolToValue(String symbol)
    {
        int index = Array.IndexOf(cardSymbols, symbol);
        if (index != -1)
        {
            return cardValues[index];
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Value Not In Table");
        }
    }

    public Int32 GetSum()
    {
        int value = 0;
        Boolean aceflag;
        for (int i = 0; i < _hand.Length; i++)
        {
            value += SymbolToValue(_hand[i].Value);
            if (String.Equals(_hand[i].Value, "A"))
            {
                aceflag = true;
            }
            else
            {
                aceflag = false;
            }
            if (aceflag == true && value <= 21)
            {
                value = value + 10;
            }
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: *for some reason ... system.Array does not contain a definition for add. ... I am not sure on how to fix this.* [It doesn't have an `Add` method - at best it's got `IList.Add` which is not supported](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Use a collection that allows you to add things.

Comment: An array's size is fixed, use a `List<Card>` instead.

Comment: It's the third question I've seen with the same code of blackjack game. I'm just wondering how many questions there will be until we finally implement your game

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your code has a lot of problems, but if you really want to do it the way you're doing it, use the index to add an item:

```
public void AddCard(Card card)
{
    if (_cardCount >= MAX_CARDS)
    {
        throw new Exception(string.Format("This hand already contains {0} cards, " +
            "which is the maximum.", MAX_CARDS));
    }
    else
    {
        _hand[_cardCound] = card;
        _cardCount++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

An Array's size in c# is immutable so I would suggest using a List instead.

```
private List<Card> _hand = new List<Card>(MAX_CARDS);
```

Comment: Arrays are certainly not immutable.

Comment: The size of the array is `immutable` (actually fixed). Arrays are mutable by nature.

Answer (score -1):

we create a new List with the elements in an array that already exists. We use the List constructor and pass it the array. List receives this parameter and fills its values from it.

Caution:The array element type must match the List element type or compilation will fail.

Program that copies array to List: C#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program
{

    static void Main()
    {
    
        int[] arr = new int[3]; // New array with 3 elements
    
        arr[0] = 2;
    

        arr[1] = 3;
    
        arr[2] = 5;
    
        List<int> list = new List<int>(arr); // Copy to List
    
        Console.WriteLine(list.Count);       // 3 elements in List
   
     }

}


Output : 3
```

Array is not good for your code in c# list is used array is not a good option. So use list type data. You can use list and store every type data in this object and convert it in any type and you can also get single data from list  using a loop. It so easy to use it and implement so use list it good and easy for code .

First, we declare a List of int values. We create a new List of unspecified size and adds four prime numbers to it. Values are stored in the order added. There are other ways to create Lists—this is not the simplest.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program
{
    
  static void Main()
   
   {
    
     List<int> list = new List<int>();
    
     list.Add(2);
    
     list.Add(3);
    
     list.Add(5);
    
     list.Add(7);
  
   }

}
```